# ¿Cómo iniciar sesión en PostgreSQL luego de haber recibido un fallo de autentificación?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

He estado trabajando con una base de datos en *PostgreSQL* y *pgAdmin III* para *Windows 10* pero un día al tratar de abrirlo y conectarme a mi servidor de pruebas no me permitió el acceso mostrando el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo resolver este error? ¿A qué se debe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por su ayuda. Logré resolver el problema. Sólo hay que editar el archivo pg_hba.conf de Postgres y dejar únicamente estas líneas en la parte de la configuración de conexiones:

TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Y listo, problema resuelto.

Answer (score 1):

Los errores de autentificación desde pgadmin pueden deberse a varios motivos. A mí los más comunes que se me han presentado son:

1. Tu servidor de PostgreSQL no está iniciado.
2. Estás poniendo mal tus credenciales

Lo que podrías hacer es iniciar una terminal CMD (tecla windows + r), e introducir lo siguiente:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -h localhost
```

Estos son los credenciales que trae por defecto.

También estaría bien que dejases una captura de pantalla con los datos que has introducido desde PgAdmin.

Otro posible error que a mí me ha pasado bastante con PgAdmin III es que como por defecto PostgreSQL no trae contraseña produce ese error. En ese caso tendrías que introducir desde el CMD de windows el comando que te he comentado. Una vez dentro de la base de datos (desde el CMD por supuesto) introduces:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'tu_password';
```

Y debería aceptarte los credenciales desde PgAdmin.

Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Asegurate de estar poniendo bien las credenciales de usuario y contraseña, es muy recurrente ese error, justo hace rato me paso eso. En dado caso que ni así funcione, dejo [este enlace](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/51C1BE37.5070409%40ort.edu.uy) para que puedas cambiar tu contraseña en *Windows*.

Comment: No te olvides de marcar mi respuesta como correcta si fue así. Saludos